# Modified ColorPicker dialog error

Tags: android, colors, dialog

I want to use an advanced colorpicker dialog rather than google's default one

Thus, I decided to use following code from
(https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Settings/blob/527f17f73f76feee76f50d022c7b7629d288e312/src/com/android/settings/notificationlight/ColorPickerView.java)
[image]

--ColorPickerView.java(see the above link)

--CreativePainterActivity.java

```
package jlab.creativePainter;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import com.google.ads.*;


import jlab.creativePainter.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.media.*;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient;
import android.net.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.*;


//public class CreativePainterActivity extends Activity implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {
public class CreativePainterActivity extends Activity implements ColorPickerView.OnColorChangedListener {
MyView vw;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaneState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstaneState);

      vw = new MyView(this);
      setContentView(vw);

      //addContentView(R.layout.main);
      addContentView( LayoutInflater.from( this ).inflate( R.layout.main, null), new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT ) ) ;

      //adMob
      AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
      AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
      re.setTesting(true);
      adview.loadAd(re);

      mPaint = new Paint();

      mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
      mPaint.setDither(true);
      mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
      mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
      mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
      mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
      mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

      mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 }, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
      mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);


      //
      Toast.makeText(this, "Draw it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


  }

  private Paint       mPaint;
  private MaskFilter  mEmboss;
  private MaskFilter  mBlur;

  public void colorChanged(int color) {
      mPaint.setColor(color);
  }

  protected class MyView extends View {

      private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
      private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

      private Bitmap  mBitmap, mBitmap2;
      private Canvas  mCanvas;
      private Path    mPath;
      private Paint   mBitmapPaint;

      public MyView(Context context){
          super(context);

          ///added by JLab
          setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
          //
          mPath = new Path();
          mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);


      }

      @Override
      protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
          super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
          mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
          mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
      }

      public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

          canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
          //added from fingerPaint.java
          //canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);

          canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
          //added By JEON
          canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

      }


      private float mX, mY;
      private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

      private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
          mPath.reset();
          mPath.moveTo(x, y);
          mX = x;
          mY = y;
      }
      private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
          float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
          float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
          if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
              mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
              mX = x;
              mY = y;
          }
      }
      private void touch_up() {
          mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
          // commit the path to our offscreen
          mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
          // kill this so we don't double draw
          mPath.reset();
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
          float x = event.getX();
          float y = event.getY();

          switch (event.getAction()) {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                  touch_start(x, y);
                  invalidate();
                  break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                  touch_move(x, y);
                  invalidate();
                  break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  touch_up();
                  invalidate();
                  break;
          }
          return true;
      }

      //clear method
      public void clear() {
          if (mCanvas != null) {
              int color;
              color = mPaint.getColor();
              mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
              mCanvas.drawPaint(mPaint);
              invalidate();
              mPaint.setColor(color);
              //mFadeSteps = MAX_FADE_STEPS;
          }
      }


  }//end of the class MyView

  //Menu Items
  private static final int COLOR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST;
  private static final int CLEAR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
//  private static final int EMBOSS_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 2;
  private static final int LOAD_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 2;
  private static final int BLUR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 3;
  private static final int ERASE_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 4;
//  private static final int SRCATOP_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 5;
  private static final int SAVE_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 5;

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

      menu.add(0, COLOR_MENU_ID, 0, "Color").setShortcut('3', 'c');
      menu.add(0, CLEAR_MENU_ID, 0, "Clear").setShortcut('4', 's');
//      menu.add(0, EMBOSS_MENU_ID, 0, "Emboss").setShortcut('4', 's');
      menu.add(0, LOAD_MENU_ID, 0, "LOAD").setShortcut('5', 'z');
      menu.add(0, BLUR_MENU_ID, 0, "Blur").setShortcut('5', 'z');
      menu.add(0, ERASE_MENU_ID, 0, "Erase").setShortcut('5', 'z');
//      menu.add(0, SRCATOP_MENU_ID, 0, "SrcATop").setShortcut('5', 'z');
      menu.add(0, SAVE_MENU_ID, 0, "SAVE").setShortcut('5', 'z');

      /****   Is this the mechanism to extend with filter effects?
      Intent intent = new Intent(null, getIntent().getData());
      intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
      menu.addIntentOptions(
                            Menu.ALTERNATIVE, 0,
                            new ComponentName(this, NotesList.class),
                            null, intent, 0, null);
      *****/
      return true;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      mPaint.setXfermode(null);
      mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
      File imageFileFolder;
      File imageFileName;

      switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case COLOR_MENU_ID:
              //new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, mPaint.getColor()).show();
              new ColorPickerView(this).draw(vw.mCanvas);

              return true;

          case CLEAR_MENU_ID:
              vw.clear();
              return true;

          /*    
          case EMBOSS_MENU_ID:
              if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mEmboss) {
                  mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
              } else {
                  mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
              }
              return true;
          */

          case LOAD_MENU_ID:
              /*
              String sdLPath;
              sdLPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
              Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdLPath+"image.jpeg");
              vw.clear();
              vw.mCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, vw.mBitmapPaint);
              invalidate();
              */

              vw.clear();
              //vw.invalidate();              
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                      startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

              return true;

          case BLUR_MENU_ID:
              if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mBlur) {
                  mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);
              } else {
                  mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
              }
              return true;

          case ERASE_MENU_ID:
              mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
              return true;
          /*    
          case SRCATOP_MENU_ID:
              mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
              mPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
              return true;
          */    
          case SAVE_MENU_ID:
              //added by JLab
              Bitmap b = vw.getDrawingCache();
              //vw.destroyDrawingCache();

              imageFileFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"CreativePainter");
              imageFileFolder.mkdir();
              FileOutputStream out = null;
              Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
              String date = fromInt(c.get(Calendar.MONTH))
                          + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                          + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.YEAR))
                          + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))
                          + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                          + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
              imageFileName = new File(imageFileFolder, date.toString() + ".jpg");
              try
              {
               out = new FileOutputStream(imageFileName);
               b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, out);
               //out.flush();
               //out.close();
               Toast.makeText(this, imageFileName.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               scanPhoto(imageFileName.toString());
               vw.destroyDrawingCache();
               //out = null;
              } catch (Exception e)
              {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "An error has occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }

              /////
              return true;
      }//end SWITCH
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  //Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(requestCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  //Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(resultCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
   Uri targetUri = data.getData();
   Bitmap bitmap;
   Bitmap bitmap2;

   //resize the image
   Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
   int width = display.getWidth();
   int height = display.getHeight();


   try {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
    //resize
    bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
    vw.mCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0, 0, vw.mBitmapPaint);
    //invalidate();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    Toast.makeText(this, "File Not Found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  }
   vw.invalidate();
  }//end of the onActivityResult method

  //scanPhoto method

  private MediaScannerConnection msConn;
  public void scanPhoto(final String imageFileName)
  {

      msConn = new MediaScannerConnection(this, new MediaScannerConnectionClient()
  {
  public void onMediaScannerConnected()
  {
      msConn.scanFile(imageFileName, null);
      Log.i("msClient obj  in Photo Utility","connection established");

  }
  public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri)
  {
  Log.i("msClient obj in Photo Utility","scan completed");
  }
  });
  msConn.connect();
  } 

  ///added
  public String fromInt(int val)
  {
  return String.valueOf(val);
  }
public void onColorChanged(int color) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}//end of the class CreativePainterActivity
```

However, after put the application to the android device

it shows error(log cat)

```
09-01 05:08:02.617: E/AndroidRuntime(15718): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 05:08:02.617: E/AndroidRuntime(15718): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-01 05:08:02.617: E/AndroidRuntime(15718):    at jlab.creativePainter.ColorPickerView.onDraw(ColorPickerView.java:195)
09-01 05:08:02.617: E/AndroidRuntime(15718):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13458)
09-01 05:08:02.617: E/AndroidRuntime(15718):    at jlab.creativePainter.CreativePainterActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(CreativePainterActivity.java:228)
...
```

I think that the error may occured by the following statement

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case COLOR_MENU_ID:
//new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, mPaint.getColor()).show();
**new ColorPickerView(this).draw(vw.mCanvas);**
return true;
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly in ColorPickerView there is method onDraw:

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mDrawingRect.width() <= 0 || mDrawingRect.height() <= 0) {
            return;
        }
        drawSatValPanel(canvas);
        drawHuePanel(canvas);
        drawAlphaPanel(canvas);
    }
```

As you can see there is mDrawingRect object(he is null). He is initialized in onSizeChanged

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    mDrawingRect = new RectF();
    mDrawingRect.left = mDrawingOffset + getPaddingLeft();
    mDrawingRect.right = w - mDrawingOffset - getPaddingRight();
    mDrawingRect.top = mDrawingOffset + getPaddingTop();
    mDrawingRect.bottom = h - mDrawingOffset - getPaddingBottom();

    setUpSatValRect();
    setUpHueRect();
    setUpAlphaRect();
}
```

So if you call draw() immediately before adding view to layout onSizeChanged isn't called. Initialize mDrawindRect in constructor or don't call draw() method before adding to layout.

Comment: thanks.. then..  could you tell me how should I fix my codes?

Comment: Initialize mDrawingRect in constructor with some values or don't use draw() method. Why don't you attach ColorPickerView to your layout? Or create dialog with it. Use it as every other view.

Comment: Thanks.. Marcin.. I know what you said.. but could you give me a source code example?

Comment: addContentView(new ColorPickerView(this), new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); I dont know what your Activity do and how it looks like so it's hard to provide best example for you.